# Cloud datastore queries, where is the key?

Tags: go, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have stored some data on Google cloud datastore.

Querying the data is not an issue, I can use an iterator and get the properties of the data.
example;
https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#projection_queries

```
var priorities []int
var percents []float64
it := client.Run(ctx, query)
for {
    var task Task
    if _, err := it.Next(&task); err == iterator.Done {
            break
    } else if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
    }
    priorities = append(priorities, task.Priority)
    percents = append(percents, task.PercentComplete)
}
```

I can access the Properties of the entity with no problem but have no idea on how to read/access the keys.

How do I get the keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see [here](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/datastore#Iterator.Next) that the iterator returns the associated key when calling `Next`. In the example above it is not needed and is therefore discarded by using the [blank identifier](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Blank_identifier), i.e. `_, err := it.Next(&task)`. If you want the key then do not discard it:

```golang
for {
    var task Task
    key, err := it.Next(&task)
    if err != nil && err != iterator.Done {
         return err
    } else if err == iterator.Done {
         break
    }
    priorities = append(priorities, task.Priority)
    percents = append(percents, task.PercentComplete)

    // do something with key
}
```